# merge new account into old

Tags: support, merge-accounts

Allen Hatcher has asked that his new, mysterious account, be merged into an existing one.

SEE

[If a binary quadratic form primitively represents $n$ and $n^3$, must it be the identity form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3985889/if-a-binary-quadratic-form-primitively-represents-n-and-n3-must-it-be-the/4034493#4034493)

Answer (score 2):

Start here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Thanks, Asaf; I pasted your link into a comment at his recent answer. I  had already put a link to this Metamucil question.